# How can I find the average of an integer variable that is changed 5 times from a while loop nested inside a for loop? C#

Tags: c#

Sorry, it was hard to phrase that question.

My console "program" uses a while loop to randomly generate a number between 1 & 6 (like a dice). The goal is to generate (roll) the number 6. It also has a variable inside it called attempts to calculate how many attempts it took to generate (roll) the number 6.

I want to run this console "program" 5 times (I used a for loop) and then calculate the average of the attempts variable from each iteration of the for loop.

My question is, how can I extract the attempts variable from each iteration and then calculate the average of the attempts.

This is the code I have so far:

```
// creates the random # generator

Random numberGen = new Random();

// Runs the while loop 5 times

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

//Declares the roll and attempts variables to start at 0

    int roll = 0;
    int attempts = 0;

//Runs the number generator to create a number between 1-6. Prints the output.

    while (roll != 6) {
        roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled: " + roll);
        attempts++;
}
//Prints the # of attempts after each iteration of the for loop.

Console.WriteLine("Total attempts: " + attempts);

//I was trying to use an if statement to transfer the attempt variable into a different variable after each iteration, however this does not work, my brain is fried at this point.

int attempt1, attempt2, attempt3, attempt4, attempt5;
    if (i == 0) {
        int attempts = attempt1;
    }
    else if (i == 1) {
        int attempts = attempt2;
    }
    else if (i == 3) {
        int attempts = attempt3;
    }
    else if (i == 4) {
        int attempts = attempt4;
    }
    else {
        int attempts = attempt5;
    }


} 


Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Accumulate the intermediate results and divide it by 5. Or put all results in a list and use linqs average.

Comment: Can I spoil the surprise and tell you it's 6?

Comment: I added code below that works. Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on mathis1337's answer, you can do the same thing without a list by summing each term of the arithmetic mean:

```
    Random numberGen = new Random();

    var mean = 0f;
    const int count = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        //Declares the roll and attempts variables to start at 0

        int roll = 0;
        int attempts = 0;

        //Runs the number generator to create a number between 1-6. Prints the output.

        while (roll != 6)
        {
            roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine($"You rolled: {roll}");
            attempts++;
        }
        //Prints the # of attempts after each iteration of the for loop.

        Console.WriteLine($"Total attempts: {attempts}" );
        mean += ((float)attempts) / count;

    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Average attempts: {mean}");
```

This is effectively what MPelletier was suggesting in their answer as well

Comment: Great thank you! This is what I was looking for! Also thank you @mathis1337 for your answer as well. I'm just learning C# right now and will be getting to lists next lesson, so I wanted to try to use only the knowledge that I had at the moment.

Comment: I also see where I was going wrong, I ended up trying to write something like mean = 0 + attempts / count; However I see that it has to be mean = mean + attempts / count; to work because it will store the value outside the loop rather than erasing it each time! 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
Random numberGen = new Random();

// Runs the while loop 5 times

List<int> attemptsList = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    //Declares the roll and attempts variables to start at 0

    int roll = 0;
    int attempts = 0;

    //Runs the number generator to create a number between 1-6. Prints the output.

    while (roll != 6)
    {
        roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled: " + roll);
        attempts++;
    }
    //Prints the # of attempts after each iteration of the for loop.

    Console.WriteLine("Total attempts: " + attempts);
    attemptsList.Add(attempts);

}

var avgAttempts = attemptsList.Average();

Console.WriteLine("Average attempts: " + avgAttempts);
```

Comment: Im pretty sure your right that works! But im trying to do it without a list

Comment: What do you want to use? You need to declare something outside of your forloop to store the values. So you'll need something to store them. You can use an array, strings, other things, but a List makes it quite simple to achieve what you are wanting. You say you want to "extract the values" well adding them to a List<int> does just that.

Comment: I should also add everytime your for loop starts over it wipes out the past values, so you need to declare a variable of some kind outside of it at the top to store values. The answer below me says same thing. You must declare a variable.

Comment: @willworkfortesla The list is infinitely better than your approach of `attempt1`-`attempt4`. Your approach blatantly violates the DRY principle, and mathis1337's approach corrects that. If you want to do it without a list you can use Welford's method to calculate the average

Answer (score 1):

An average is the sum divided by the count. Declare a variable to accumulate the sum, then divide by 5. Mind your data types!

Comment: I understand how to get the average, just not sure where to place the variable to accumulate the sum from each iteration

Comment: In your while loop. Just add the value of roll to your sum.

Comment: I'm trying to get the accumulated value for the attempts variable. I tried the following, but it just gives me the last iteration.
Added:
        results = 0 + attempts;

to while loop